# Getting the value of sql.NullString with reflection

Tags: go

I'd like to get the value of all the fields in a struct that aren't empty. This works for simple primitives (`string`, `int`, etc.), but not for struct types such as `sql.NullString`.

Very simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type fooT struct {
        NullS sql.NullString
    }

    values := reflect.ValueOf(fooT{})

    field := values.Field(0)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(field)

    iface := v.Interface().(sql.NullString)

    fmt.Println(iface)
}
```

This gives a panic:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is reflect.Value, not sql.NullString
```

I don't understand this, since the `Interface` method should return an `interface{}` (and not a `reflect.Value`) which I can then type assert (?)

First I thought I was maybe using type conversions only works for primitives, but a quick test script:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type fooT struct {
        NullS sql.NullString
    }

    foo := fooT{NullS: sql.NullString{"It's an Aardvark!", true}}

    var iface interface{}
    iface = foo.NullS

    fmt.Printf("%T -> %#v\n", iface, iface)
    fmt.Printf("%T -> %#v -> %#v\n", iface.(sql.NullString), iface.(sql.NullString),
        iface.(sql.NullString).Valid)
}
```

Reveals that this should work?

---

The full code I'm using:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type fooT struct {
    ID    int64
    Foo   string
    NullS sql.NullString
    FooQ  sql.NullString
}

func main() {
    foo := fooT{
        ID:    42,
        NullS: sql.NullString{"Your mother was a hamster", true},
    }

    types := reflect.TypeOf(foo)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(foo)

    changed := ""
    for i := 0; i < types.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := types.Field(i)
        field := values.Field(i)

        switch field.Type().Kind() {
        // Works
        case reflect.String:
            if field.String() != "" {
                changed += fmt.Sprintf("<strong>%s</strong>: %v<br>\n",
                    fieldType.Name, field.String())
            }
        default:
            switch field.Type().String() {
            case "sql.NullString":
                v := reflect.ValueOf(field)

                // NullS: reflect.Value -> sql.NullString{String:"Your mother was a hamster", Valid:true}
                iface := v.Interface()
                fmt.Printf("%s: %T -> %#v\n",
                    fieldType.Name, iface, iface)

                // panic: interface conversion: interface is reflect.Value, not sql.NullString
                iface2 := v.Interface().(sql.NullString)
                fmt.Printf("%s: %T -> %#v\n",
                    fieldType.Name, iface2, iface2)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf(changed)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for including a complete program. I think you don't need that `reflect.ValueOf` in the NullString case (which, note, you don't have for the string case). I may be misunderstanding the question but I'll post an answer with a couple code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that an extra `reflect.ValueOf` meant that you had a `reflect.Value` *referring to another `reflect.Value`*, not to the `NullString`. The way `Printf` formatted it kind of obscured that. It looks like `values.Field(i)` returns the `reflect.Value` you need. [Here's your program](https://play.golang.org/p/5bSaxWHvbs) minimally modified by taking out the `ValueOf`:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type fooT struct {
    ID    int64
    Foo   string
    NullS sql.NullString
    FooQ  sql.NullString
}

func main() {
    foo := fooT{
        ID:    42,
        NullS: sql.NullString{"Your mother was a hamster", true},
    }

    types := reflect.TypeOf(foo)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(foo)

    changed := ""
    for i := 0; i < types.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldType := types.Field(i)
        field := values.Field(i)

        switch field.Type().Kind() {
        // Works
        case reflect.String:
            if field.String() != "" {
                changed += fmt.Sprintf("<strong>%s</strong>: %v<br>\n",
                    fieldType.Name, field.String())
            }
        default:
            switch field.Type().String() {
            case "sql.NullString":
        iface := field.Interface()
                fmt.Printf("%s: %T -> %#v\n",
                    fieldType.Name, iface, iface)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf(changed)
}
```

You may be able to simplify more by using a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to do most of the work, [like so](https://play.golang.org/p/VZuoIScAtI):

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type fooT struct {
    ID    int64
    Foo   string
    NullS sql.NullString
    FooQ  sql.NullString
}

func main() {
    foo := fooT{
        ID:    42,
        NullS: sql.NullString{"Your mother was a hamster", true},
    }

    values := reflect.ValueOf(foo)

    changed := ""
    for i := 0; i < values.NumField(); i++ {
        v := values.Field(i)
        f := v.Interface()
        switch f := f.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println("string:", f)
        case sql.NullString:
            fmt.Println("NullString:", f.Valid, f.String)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", v.Type(), f)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf(changed)
}
```